# Is there something wrong with the logic I've applied in this conditional statement?

Tags: php

This is basically part of the paypal IPN , I'm checking to see if the order ID that was sent(txn_id) already exists. If it does I don't want anything to happen, if it doesn't then post to the database. It seems to post to the databse even though it exists, why is it doing that?

```
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email']; 
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];

$txn_sql =" SELECT * FROM test where item2 = $txn_id ";
$order_num = mysqli_query($Connection, $txn_sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($order_num);

if ($num_rows > 0){

  $unique = 'no';
}
else {

  $unique = 'yes';
}



if ($receiver_email == "seller@paypalsandbox.com" && $payment_status == "Completed" && $unique =="yes" ) {

$Connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw", "db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $sql="INSERT INTO test (item1, item2)
 VALUES ('$txn_id', '$unique')";

 $do = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);
```

I get, the value I sent along with "yes" for item2 all the time, shouldn't it not post at all if it exists? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should use prepared statements because you don't filter the POST value `$txn_id` (SQL injection). Also helping a lot is clean code style all the way, not writing a variable with caps, other with small letters, here blankspace, but here not,...

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure `item2` field is an integer since you are comparing without `'`. Next, try to `var_dump($num_rows)` and see the real result or even `var_dump($_POST)`.

If it is really `> 1`, try to `echo $txn_sql`, copy the `sql` statement and run it to your actual database (using `navicat` or something) and see if you have problem with your database.

It may help to turn on your `display_errors` option in `php.ini` or `ini_set('display_errors", "on")` to check if you have connection issues or other errors.

I'm just answering this to help you debug your problem. Hope that helps :)

Comment: we don't know wether he is using apache, you mean `php.ini` instead of `httpd.conf`. Good advices tho!